# Why I can't access global variable in my observer?

Tags: event-observer, register, global-variable

I have a custom module. In its controller I set a global variable as shown below

```
public function someAction()
{
    if (<some_condition_met>) {
        $id = 12;
        $item =  Mage::getModel('mymodel/entity')->load($id);
        Mage::register('my_entity', $item); //registering global variable
        $this->_redirect('customer/account/login');
        return;
    }
}
```

Now I am observing on an event `controller_action_postdispatch_customer_account_loginPost`. I need to validate  my global variable there. So in my observer I tried this.

```
public function myObserver()
{
     if (<some_condition_met>) {
          $item =  Mage::registry('my_entity');
          var_dump($item);
          die();
     }
}
```

But it outputS

```
NULL
```

Why I can't get a global variable in this observer ?

I am 100% sure that, my controller successfully registers that value. I try to pass a static value. It also doesn't work.

**Side note**: when we try to get a global variable that set by a controller inside a block, it will surely return data. Here I assume i am not getting an output because, I am trying to get the global variable, during another controller action takes place. I am not sure about this point. However it seems like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The registry is only valid for one request. If you do a `$this->_redirect()`, a new request begins, so that the registry is reset. You have to use cookies if you want to store information across multiple requests.

Another possibility is to just forward to another controller, but this may not be what you want to achieve.

Comment: ya. Again you scored. I have lot of doubts today. Ready for next one. Thanks for confirming this doubt two. Cheers :)

Comment: thanks for your concept ,can you please describe briefly

Comment: But while using cookie, you just can't get cookie value just after setting it's value, cookie also won't work realtime, you want to get it realtime within a request